# Mirth losing data in mapper variables

Tags: mirth

I have a database reader channel set up that actually reads the database at 10 second intervals and sends to a web service just fine. We get a valid response from the wsdl.

However, I need to update the database record so that it is flagged as having been processed. in this case we are simple changing a field from 100 to 101. However, when I try to update the field OR send an email containing ANY data that has been stored into mapper variables I get nothing. The database does not update. Emails send blanks for fields.

When I go into the channel messages for processed messages I can see good data in the Raw Message and Encoded Message tabs. There are no values in the Mappings tab.

Any suggestions on troubleshooting?

Answer (score 1):

The Run-on-Update statement does not have access to the channel map, as it runs after message Encoding (and even the post-processor, I believe).

It DOES have access to the globalChannelMap and the responseMap. Put your new ID in the globalChannelMap and you should be good to go.

If you also want to send an email, would recommend you instead add an SMTP Writer destination (e.g., SMTP writer), which will have access to any channelMap variables created in a 'Destination 1'; as well as the globalChannelMap.

Comment: Be careful using the globalChannelMap as it is global. If you have two channels, or one channel running unsynchronized, it is possible to overwrite those values from outside of your channel.

Comment: The scope of the globalChannelMap is a single channel - there is no risk from other channels. That said, the lifetime is from each deploy, so it would be smart to clear or reset the value before processing each message.

Comment: My mistake. I misread that as globalMap. @dividius is on the ball.